# how to run a mysql query in yii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I want to make mysql query to get the highest 5 values in a column from a table,
so the query is :

```
'SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY  `uploadDate` DESC LIMIT 5'
```

how to run this query and save its value in a variable?

I prefer to use findAll() method with these options if it is possible.

Comment: `save its value in a variable` ... What have you tried?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I tried to make this:

`$sql = 'select...';
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$result=$command->execute();`

Comment: That work for me to save results of sql:
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, but if you prefer the query builder way

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->
          select('id, filename, uploadDate')->
          from('files')->
          order('uploadDate DESC')->
          limit(5)->
          queryAll();

var_dump($results);
```

Read this documentation for more detail : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder