# Yii selecting only database columns?

Tags: yii

I used findAll() in Yii to search only two columns in database. but it results in a array with that two attributes which also contains virtual variables define in Model. I only need database columns not  virtual variables. Please answer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want do that, you may write custom sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use like this:

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand('select * from your_table_name');
$row = $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

`findAll()` returns almost everything about the model that you used. But if you are overwhelmed with the results you're receiving, do a custom query instead just like in this one: [how to run a mysql query in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647572/how-to-run-a-mysql-query-in-yii)